# jQuery on click fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whe using jQuery `.on('click', ...)` the function is executed twice:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#collapsible-menu li a').click(function() {
        $('#collapsible-menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

So what happens is that the menu item goes active for an instant and then class goes away.

I have no clue why it's being fired twice. I don't want to use `event.preventDefault()` or `event.preventPropagation()` or `return false` because then clicking the link will lead nowhere.

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsible-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/expenses">Expenses</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/types">Types</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the net effect will be that that code is a no-op.

Comment: how did you verify that the click handler is executed twice? console.log, alert?

Comment: I verified it with alert

Comment: if you get two alert's on a single click, then the problem is in the code/html that is not shown - try creating jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2):

You're clicking an anchor which redirects the page to `/types`.

When you go to another page, whatever changes the javascript did, is lost.
So you're adding a class, then it redirects and the class is lost, the event handler doesn't fire twice
To avoid redirecting you can prevent the default action of the anchor

```
$('#collapsible-menu li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#collapsible-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

You ***can not*** expect to keep the class, ***and*** redirect at the same time, you have to do one or the other.

Comment: so I should redirect via javascript?

Comment: @dabadaba There is no point redirecting by jQuery either unless you have a way to set the active state from code-behind or by some script you are not showing us

Comment: I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: You simply can't redirect and set a class at the same time, the class would have to be set on the page you're redirecting to, and for that you would need some other way than a click to know what element should be active

Comment: It's not supposed to! Again, you either have to add the class and stay on the same page, or go to another page and loose the class, that's how it works, HTML is ***stateless*** !

Comment: While I see the point you made here, there is small chance that OP wants to temporary switch to `active` before new response arrives, in which case he should probably redirect from JS. That, of course, won't solve the problem from title.

Comment: so redirecting via javascript is the only choice to make the link work? Also, yeah, why is it being fired twice?

Comment: Even if you redirect with javascript, the class will be lost ?